# XNA Mediaplayer.Play() starts playing at different times across computers?

Tags: xna, monogame

I'm trying to develop a rhythm game in Monogame. The notes are frame rate independent and work consistently over different computers, but the song playing does not. Right now I have it hooked up so the notes spawn and MediaPlayer.Play() do not start until I hit a key (so it's outside of loadcontent/initialize like I've seen other solutions suggest). The song does not start playing until I hit the "I" key (gets checked in Update). However, the song seems to start playing at different times across different devices. I pull down the project on both my laptop (on battery) and desktop, and hit the "I" key at the same time on both, and I get different results on my laptop. Sometimes it'll be seconds ahead of the desktop, other times it'll be a second or two behind (this is usually the case). It seems pretty consistent on desktop. I'd try more than a dozen times and everything is still synced, but not on my laptop. I'm worried this is something that works only on my PC but not on others.

I've tried enabling fixedTimeStep and setting FPS to 60 (and setting the TargetElapsedTime to the window title ensuring that they are indeed both hitting 60) and I still get inconsistent results. I've read from other answers about using PlayPosition from the MediaPlayer class, but that property is readonly so I'm not quite how I could use that.

At first, I thought my notes were simply dependent on frame rate, but after setting FPS and fixedTimeStep, and also holding my laptop up to my desktop monitor they match up perfectly. It's just the song not syncing up. I'm still a newbie to XNA but I couldn't find anyone else reporting different song starting timings like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of a solution the *second* I got out of bed the next morning. I figured there must be some overhead on MediaPlayer.Play(), but I wondered if I could start it, pause it, then resume instead. Turns out, there is a Pause() and Resume() method which is what what missing from making this work.

So! If anyone else out there is having similar issues, here's what I did. I kept a key to activate MediaPlayer.Play(), but immediately added MediaPlayer.Pause() after. Then I got another key to resume the song, and the notes spawned when the song was resumed. So pressing "I" played the song and paused it immediately. Pressing "R" resumed the song and started spawning the notes.

Comment: To be fair, the media player in XNA has a bit of a learning curve due to, for instance, not having public write access to `PlayPosition`, I don't blame you for having some struggle with it.

Comment: Yea, the Play() call is loading the video and buffering up frames, which takes a different amount of time depending on your disk access speed / etc. The Play/Pause trick is one ive seen used before.